# Missing operation name or the operation name is invalid

Tags: 2013, powershell, stsadm

I run the following power shell command inside SharePoint 2013 power shell window:-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> stsadm -o gl-fixpublishingpagespagelayouturl -url "http://gvstg01/wikilibrary/52" -scope webapplication
```

but i got the following error:-

```
Missing operation name or the operation name is invalid.
```

can anyone adivce what is wrong with my powershell command?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am sure Gary Lapointe's custom stsadm will not work in 2013.

You need to do the following things.

- 1st deploy the Lapointe.wsp to install all the custom commands. Download it from here [:SharePoint 2013 Server Cmdlets (x86, x64)](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/)
- Once above solution succesfully installed then all his custom command will be available.
- Now you to run the following command. [Repair-SPPageLayoutUrl](http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2013&Cmdlet=Repair-SPPageLayoutUrl)

From this page you can see all the aviable custom commands.

http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx

Comment: so can I just use Repair-SPPageLayoutUrl command ?, If the answer is Yes, then how i can write this command, as seems there are many parameters such as RegexSearchString ,RegexReplaceString, etc which i do not understand .. can u adivce –

Comment: did you see the example at the end of page, give you exactly what you have to write.Mostly parameters or optionals....you can check example 1 may be fix your problem

Comment: thanks for the reply, which example you are talking about, thnaks.